# Instalei o XAMPP mas não consigo iniciar o apache, Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp

Instalei o `XAMPP` no Windows e não estou conseguindo iniciar o apache, o erro que vejo é:

```
18:32:57  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
18:32:57  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
18:32:57  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
18:32:57  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
18:32:57  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
18:32:57  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
18:32:57  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: Achei a resposta na versão em inglês, fiz a pergunta para poder traduzir a resposta, segue:

> Se você está utilizando a última versão do skype, vá em Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection e desabilite "Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections"

> Desconecte-se e feche o Skype. Tente iniciar o Apach agora.

Link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/18995458#18995458?newreg=fa5ebf82ca8541a5a3d317a845d71179

Comment: DBX8 - adiciona a tag XAMPP, vc consegue?

Comment: **NOTA:** No Windows existem varios serviços / programas que usam a porta 80 (inclusive da propria Microsoft), se nenhuma solução funcionar tente com outra porta para ver o que acontece.

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80485/3635

Answer (score 11):

Resposta colocada como comentário:

Se você está utilizando a última versão do Skype:

- Vá em `Tools` > `Options` > `Advanced` > `Connection`.
- Desabilite a opção `Use port 80 and 443 for alternatives for incoming connections`.

  [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
- Desconecte-se e feche o Skype.
- Inicie o Apache novamente.

*[Referência](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300377/xampp-apache-error-apache-shutdown-unexpectedly/18995458#18995458)

Answer (score 4):

Aconteceu a mesma coisa comigo, mas como eu estou sem skype tive que procurar outra solução. **Para quem não tem skype e teve o mesmo problema**, segue o jeito que eu resolvi o meu:

1- Abri o gerenciador de tarefas (Estou usando o Windows 7)

2- Procurei em Aplicativos alguma coisa relacionada a isso (mysqld.exe *32)

3- Finalizei o processo mysqld.exe *32

4- Iniciei o Xampp e o Apache voltou a funcionar normalmente.

Fonte: http://www.tecgirl.com.br/2015/12/06/problemas-em-iniciar-o-apache-do-xampp/

Answer (score 3):

para saber exatamente o que esta escutando a porta 80 (ou qualquer outra porta) execute o cmd como administrador, e digite: netstat -anb

no exemplo abaixo, o apache.exe esta escutando a porta 80 em todos os IPs da maquina.

```
    C:\Windows\system32>netstat -anb

    Conexões ativas

      Proto  Endereço local         Endereço externo       Estado
      TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
     [apache.exe]
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Nem sempre é problema de porta. No meu caso, foi outro problema: Diretório raiz não encontrado.

Descobri abrindo o `Xampp -> Shell` (debaixo do botão "Netstat") e rodei o comando `apache_start.bat` e então recebi a mensagem de que ele não estava encontrando o diretório raiz especificado no httpd.conf.

Atualizei o caminho e iniciou sem problemas.

Answer (score 0):

Além do Skype, como disseram nas outras respostas, faça o seguinte:

No menu iniciar, digite "recursos" e clique em "Ativar ou desativar recursos do Windows". Aguarde alguns minutos.

[image: menu iniciar]

---

Quando a janela de "Recursos do Windows" abrir, desmarque a caixinha "Serviços de Informações da Internet". E pressione OK. O processo pode demorar alguns minutos. Depois reinicie o computador.

[image: recursos do windows]

---

Outra coisa a fazer, [que foi explicado pela @Marcielli Oliveira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/102259/622), é: assim que instalar o XAMPP, iniciar o apache e der erro, abra o gerenciador de tarefas e mate todos os processos **httpd.exe *32** e **mysqld.exe *32**. Feito isso, volte a iniciar o Apache.

Answer (score 0):

Uma das causas deste erro é a existência de outro programa/serviço que pode estar a utilizar a porta 80, como o IIS (Internet Information Service) por exemplo.

Para ter a certeza que a porta 80 não está a ser utilizada por outro programa, abra a Linha de Comandos (abra como administrador no Windows 7) e executa o comando:

**C:>netstat -a -b**

Se outro programa estiver a utilizar a porta 80, será listado o nome do executável.