# Apache não inicia o serviço no windows 10

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

Estou usando o XAMPP e desde que mudei para o windows 10 ele vem com isso, antes ele não ativava o apache, depois procurei alguns tutoriais na internet e achei [este](http://www.zeeronsolutions.com/fix-xampp-apache-not-starting-because-port-80-in-use-issue/).

Resolveu um dos problemas, pois depois que fiz os passos deste vídeo o apache passou a iniciar, mas quando entro no localhost só fica uma página em branco. Mesmo tentando acessar outro diretório da pasta `htdocs` fica na mesma.

Comment: você trocou a portão padrão(80) pela qual? e como está chamando as urls dos sistemas?

Comment: Se você estiver usando o Skype na seu PC ele costumar conflitar com o Apache :/

Comment: De acordo com a resposta do Alexandre Borela o problema foi a troca da porta ao seguir o tutorial.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Eu tive o mesmo problema com o windows 10, o que acontece é que existe um serviço provavelmente ligado ao IIS(express acredito) que também é um servidor web, ele vem por padrão ativado, para resolver isso sem trocar a porta padrão do apache, aperte <kbd>winkey</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> e digite `services.msc` procure por: `Serviço de Publicação da World Wide Web` (`World Wide Web Publishing Service` em inglês), primeiramente pare ele depois deixe o serviço para ser iniciado manualmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sabe porque o Windows 10 ta vindo com IIS habilitado ou se pararam nas últimas versões? A possibilidade de virus se aproveitarem disso seria muito grande :/

Comment: Este é o procedimento mais correto para esse caso. A Microsoft inventa demais. Já tão chamando o Windows 10 de Windows NSA Edition (http://www.rt.com/usa/311304-new-windows-privacy-issues/)

Comment: O Windows 10 não vem com o IIS por padrão habilitado. Pode ser outro problema que está iniciando esse serviço. Quem gosta de usar a porta 80 é o Skype :)

Comment: Nossa!!! Mto obrigada!
Finalmente csegui desbloquear a porta 80 para o uso do Apache.
O que estava bloquenado era o "Serviço de Publicação da World Wide Web mesmo". \o/

Comment: Puts, me ajudou demais!

Answer (score 8):

Se você seguiu o tutorial e mudou a porta que o apache está escutando, então terá que digitar: localhost:1234 onde 1234 é a nova porta que configurou.

Answer (score 7):

Seu problema pode estar no fato da porta 80/443 já estar ocupada por outro processo. Você pode utilizar um utilitário para confirmar quem está utilizando essas portas, como o [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html).

Você pode descobrir também pela linha de comando:

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

Após descobrir o processo que está usando a porta 80, verifique o `PID` do processo e descobra que é o culpado com (trocando o 2160 pelo `PID`):

```
tasklist /FI "PID eq 2160"
```

Exemplo:

[image: Comandos]

---

Na maioria dos casos, o culpado é o Skype.

Para desabilitar o uso desses portas, vá em **Ferramentas** > **Opções**, depois na guia **Configurações avançadas** > **Conexão** e por fim desmarque a opção para usar as portas 80 e 443

[image: Janela do Skype]

Comment: É a primeira coisa que eu faço.

Comment: Otima dica a do `tasklist` e do `netstat`

Comment: a dica do Skype resolveu pra min. vlwwww

Comment: Que bom @Lipearu. Caso a resposta foi útil você pode votar positivamente. Faça um [tour] para entender como funciona o Stackoverflow.