# Wamp não funciona no windows 10?

Tags: wamp

Instalei o windows 10 e o wamp n liga, fica " Servidor offline", ele ainda n é compativel com o windows 10?

Comment: Você tem alguma mensagem de erro ? ja tive um problema no windows 10 com wamp, verifica se você tem o IIS, se tiver pare ele e reinicie o wamp, abra o cmd.exe como administrador e faça `iisreset /stop`, e reinicie o wamp.

Comment: Sou novo em programação, mas usava o WAMP no Windows 8 e agora estou usando MAMP no Windows 10.
À princípio não vi diferença e ambos atendem minhas necessidades. Abraços.

Comment: Tente esse procedimento http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/80490/91

Comment: Consegui resolver, a primeira coisa que fiz foi ir a "services.msc", e coloquei os "Serviços de Publicação WWW" em manual (tentei reiniciar o WAMP e continuou sem dar).  Depois fui aqui: http://i.imgur.com/9NMJuRv.png e ativei essas 4 funcionalidades. Consegui ligar o WAMP e está tudo normal agora :D

Answer (score 0):

Se você não conseguir de alguma forma executar o WAMP no Windows 10, e não desejar instalá-lo numa máquina virtual (VirtualBox, VMware ou Virtual PC), há ainda possibilidade de usar o *VMWare ThinApp* (http://www.vmware.com/br/products/thinapp).
O ThinApp encapsula a aplicação num determinado OS e a partir daí executa em qualquer outro OS.

Ajuda relacionada:
Is it possible to thinapp a server like WampServer?
https://communities.vmware.com/thread/408023

Comment: Ja consegui resolver :D