# Ao abrir um ficheiro php com localhost/ficheiro.php a pagina aparece em branco

Tags: php, xampp

Xampp nao me esta a criar o servidor local

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao site. Você deseja fazer um formulário de contato? Você instalou o xampp em sua máquina? Você sabe olhar log?

Comment: Crie um arquivo simples com o conteúdo, `<?php echo "hello word 2016";` a tela não deve ficar em branco. Não se acessa uma página web por `file///c:\ ....` somente por `http://endereco.com`

Comment: Obrigado pelas boas vindas. É um formulario que dps envia automaticamente para o email as informacoes apresentadas pelo visitante. Sim instalei, ja mudei os Ports e tudo. vou criar um arquivo simples, e ja lhe digo algo

Comment: Continua a aparecer tudo em branco

Comment: Então o modulo do apache foi instalado errado.

Comment: tenho de reinstalar?

Comment: Desinstale, faça uma instalação nova(limpa) e teste aquele arquivo simples e volta aqui para contar o resultado.

Comment: aqui nao e possivel por prints? pk ja reinstalei e continua a nao funcionar,mas apareceu me uma mensagem ao instalar. Porque eu estou numa mini rede local entre computadores e secalhar e por isso que nao da

Comment: Coloca o print ai, o que diz a mensagem?

Comment: A mensagem diz:"Important! Because an activated User Account Control(UAC) on your system some functions of XAMPP are possibly restricted.With UAC please avoid to install XAMPP to C:\Program Files(x86)(missing write permissions). OR deactivate UAC with msconfig after this setup."

Comment: Instalou como admin?

Comment: se executar o instalador como administrador, aparece a mensagem na mesma

Comment: Qual versão do xampp está usando? qual versão do windows é?

Comment: xampp 5.6.15 / windows 10

Comment: Olha isso => [Apache não inicia o serviço no windows 10](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80485/91)

Comment: obrigado ja ta tudo

Comment: Deu certo? funcinou?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando acessando um servidor web pelo seu browser, verificar seus arquivos pelo caminho físico na barra de endereço, tal como: "`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/form_contato.php`", abrirá o código php puro. Para abri-lo com suas funcionalidades codificadas tente abrir o seu exemplo pela seguinte url:

```
http://localhost/form_contato.php
```

Comment: Fiz como disse e nao me aparece nada, aparece uma pagina em branco

Comment: Provavelmente seu servidor web ainda não esta ativo @Leonoliveira, se estiver no windows, procure a bandeja do sistema e ative o ser servidor web (xamp) por ali.

Comment: Bandeja do sistema? 
refere se a abrir em administrador??