# Erro ao colocar wamp server online

Tags: wamp

Atualmente ultilizo WampServer para poder trabalhar com PHP porem quando vou colocar ele online aparece o seguinte erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

jé editei o httpd.conf o php.ini mais nada faz ele ficar online alguém pode me ajudar

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho como te dar certeza, mas vi que você está com o Skype aberto. Quando eu usava o WAMP, eu tinha um problema de conflito de porta com o Skype, mas não sei se ainda há. Esse conflito impedia o Apache de iniciar. Por via das dúvidas, vai a sugestão:

No Skype:

1. Menu Ferramentas
2. Opções...
3. Avançado
4. Conexão
5. Desmarque a caixa "Use as portas 80 e 443 como conexões de entrada adicionais"
6. Salvar
7. Reinicie o Skype
8. Reinicie o WAMP

Comment: Downvoter, o que há de errado com a resposta?

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do downvote na resposta. Eu mesmo já passei por essa situação de conflitos de portas com o wamp e foi justamente o Skype quem propiciou todo esse problema. Não sei pq os usuários do SOpt não gostam de fazer uso do bom senso...

Comment: eu não sei o motivo do downvote, uma coisa já existe uma "resposta" como esta em outra pergunta, quando a pergunta parecer que já existe uma resposta em algum lugar você deve votar para duplicar e não responder, veja http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/81560/3635. Entenda como uma critica construtiva.

Comment: Não vi que já havia uma pergunta com mesmo escopo no SOpt. Falha minha.