# Mudar a porta padrão do apache não resolve no Windows 10?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, apache

Fiz a instalação normal do xampp, após executar o xampp-control estou tendo os erros:

```
10:20:09  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
10:20:09  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:20:09  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:20:09  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:20:09  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:20:09  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this
10:20:09  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
10:20:10  [Apache]  Status change detected: stopped
10:20:10  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
10:20:10  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
10:20:10  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
10:20:10  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
10:20:10  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
10:20:10  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this
10:20:10  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums
```

Fiz a alteração da porta do apache para 83 e ssl port deixei a mesma, mais não executa, eu tenho o IIS na máquina mais nunca tive este problema.

Comment: [Apache não inicia o serviço no windows 10](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80485/91)

Comment: Eu fiz a configuração, parei o servido do IIS e deixei ele como manual, o apache funciona, mais o mysql não funciona.

Comment: Mas o problema é o apache ou mysql?

Comment: o mysql, o apache eu alterei a porta e parei o IIS,

Comment: Lembre-se que o apache só hospeda o seu site, e não seu mysql. Portanto, é necessário que vc que você realize um request tentando o servidor (localhost:83) e um request tentando acessar o mysql (localhost:3306 eu acho), após os requests verifique se essas ferramentas escreveram as tentativas de acesso em um arquivo de log :p.

Comment: Tente acessar o mysql pela linha de comando na pasta bin veja se aparece o erro no console ou poste o log de erro dele. Acho melhor criar uma pergunta exclusiva para o mysql.

Comment: Eu descobri o problema, eu tenho o ambiente java, estava iniciado e isso estava dando conflito, parei o tomcat, inicie o mysql e depois voltei o tomcat e funcionou. Agora eu tenho tudo funcionando.

Comment: Criem o costume de responder às próprias questões quando acharem a resposta sozinhos ;)