# Problema no Xampp

Tags: mysql, windows, apache, xampp, localhost

eu estou com problema pra iniciar o apache no Xampp quando aperto start aparece a sequinte  mensagem:

> Isso pode ser devido a uma porta bloqueada, falta de dependências,
>   18:17:44 [Apache] privilégios impróprios, uma falha ou um desligamento por outro método.
>   18:17:44 [Apache] Pressione o botão Logs para visualizar os logs de erros e verificar
>   18:17:44 [Apache] o Visualizador de Eventos do Windows para mais pistas
>   18:17:44 [Apache] Se precisar de mais ajuda, copie e publique este
>   18:17:44 [Apache] janela de registro inteira nos fóruns

eu já mudei de porta varias vezes e ainda não deu certo

**Alquem pode me ajudar por favor**

Comment: Caro Lucas, leu os logs? Afinal de contas é a primeira coisa que esta indicando, não é? Então provavelmente seu problema é que tem algum outro programa usando a porta 80 do apache, pode ser o Skype.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Apache não inicia o serviço no windows 10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/80485/apache-n%c3%a3o-inicia-o-servi%c3%a7o-no-windows-10)

Comment: eu li as logs mas não entendi nd

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda, mas acho que meu problema é diferente desse ai

Comment: Não pedi pra ler os logs, pedi pra trazer os logs pra cá, afinal este é o meio ideal para analisar os problemas, não temos como analisar a distancia o problema de seu computador. Tente ler as respostas da outra pergunta, não tem uma unica resposta, tem mais de uma tenta ambas PRIMEIRO.

Comment: ta certo vou mandar o logs pera ai

Comment: 84 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 17652:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Apr 28 18:42:40.231271 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 17652:tid 624] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name

Comment: [Tue Apr 28 20:27:41.425459 2020] [php7:error] [pid 8092:tid 1912] [client ::1:60857] script 'C:/Users/esdra/Desktop/sons/Xamp/htdocs/uva.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Apr 28 20:27:47.140979 2020] [php7:error] [pid 8092:tid 1900] [client ::1:60867] script 'C:/Users/esdra/Desktop/sons/Xamp/htdocs/uva.php' not found or unable to stat
[Tue Apr 28 20:29:25.981466 2020] [php7:error] [pid 8092:tid 1912] [client ::1:60989] script 'C:/Users/esdra/Desktop/sons/Xamp/htdocs/uva.php' not found or unable to stat

Comment: Os logs devem ir na pergunta, é pra isso q tem o botão EDITAR abaixo da pergunta, e tem que pegar os logs recentes e não os LOGS de ontem.

Comment: so tem as de ontem

Comment: vc tem 2 apaches instalados? Vc tem skype instalado? Você tentou as respostas que linkei acima? Veja que tem mais de uma, tem dicas lá de como localizar o programa que esta interrompendo o acesso a porta.

Comment: acho que tenho 2 apaches

Comment: esse é o problema ?

Comment: É esse o problema sim, se tivesse lido o link que te mandei acima teria entendido, tá respondido lá sobre PORTAS. ... Tá ai o problema, o apache inicia como serviço e usa a porta 80, vc não tem como usar 2 apaches na mesma porta, nem teria sentido. Salve seus projetos, desinstale tudo referente ao apache, wamp, xampp, easyphp ou qualquer outro programa similar que tenha baixado, reinicia o PC, baixa o xampp, instala e seja feliz :)

Comment: obrigado mesmo cara, é so isso que ta faltando pra mim começar meu curso de wordpress ajudou muito, valeu mesmo, vou tentar fazer isso

Answer (score -1):

O meu Apache do Xampp apresentou o mesmo problema, de uma hora para outra parou de inicializar. Foi quando verifiquei que o problema começou a ocorrer após eu instalar o VMWare Workstation (também poderá ocorrer com a instalação do programa VirtualBox), pois o mesmo utiliza a porta 443 que também é utilizada pelo Apache.

Faça o seguinte:

Identificar o que está causando o erro:

1. Verificar se a porta 443 está sendo utilizada por outro serviço/programa (também pode ocorrer o mesmo erro com a porta 80, o processo para verificação é o mesmo) :
2. Execute o Prompt de Comandos do MS-DOS, uma das formas para fazer isso é pressionando a tecla Windows + R e em Executar digite CMD e clique em OK.
3. No MS-DOS digite o comando netstat -ao e pressione ENTER.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Na listagem exibida verificamos que a porta 443 está sendo utilizada por outro serviço/programa, anote o PID do processo que está utilizando a porta 443, que no caso deste exemplo é o PID número 14320.
5. Agora vamos identificar o aplicativo que está utilizando a porta 443. Ainda no prompt de comando do MS-DOS digite o comando tasklist /fi "PID eq [número do PID]" que no caso deste exemplo o comando ficará desta forma: tasklist /fi "PID eq 14320"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

7. No resultado podemos verificar que no caso deste exemplo o serviço/programa que está utilizando a porta 443 é o vmware-hostd.exe que é utilizado para execução e utilização do aplicativo VMWare Workstation para criar máquinas virtuais.

Vamos agora as 2 soluções possíveis:

Solução 1:

1. Parar todos os serviços do VMWare Workstation e alterar as propriedades dos serviços para executar manualmente, ou seja, sempre que precisar utilizar o VMWare Workstation será necessário antes iniciar os serviços dele manualmente. Para isso, faça o seguinte procedimento:
2. Execute o Gerenciador de Serviços do Windows. Uma das formas para executá-lo é pressionado as teclas Windows + R, em Executar digite services.msc e clique em OK.
3. No Gerenciador de Serviços, localize os serviços que deseja parar e alterar suas propriedades, no caso deste exemplo é o VMWare Workstation:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

4. Como pode ser verificado na imagem, para o VMWare existe 5 serviços listados e em execução, iremos parar todos eles clicando sobre cada um deles e em seguida clicando em “Parar o serviço”. Em seguida, iremos clicar com o botão direito do mouse em cada um deles e no menu suspenso clicar em Propriedades:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

5. Nas Propriedades do Serviço, na guia Geral, em Tipo de inicialização altere para Manual e clique em OK.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

6. Agora o Apache irá iniciar normalmente e sempre que precisar utilizar o VMWare Workstation basta executar o services.msc (Gerenciador de Serviços) selecionar os serviços de VMWare e clicar em Iniciar. (Mas para isso, caso esteja utilizando o Apache terá que parar o Apache, senão poderá ocorrer erro e os serviços do VMWare não serem inicializados).

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Solução 2:

1. Alterar a porta 443 para a porta 4433 no Apache. Para isso vá até a pasta \apache\conf\extra e edite o arquivo httpd-ssl.conf alterando a linha Listen 443 para Listen 4433. No caso de nosso exemplo, acrescentamos o símbolo # antes de Listen 443 para que a linha seja interpretada como um comentário e não seja executado o comando e acrescentamos na linha abaixo o comando Listen 4433, fica definido que a porta 4433 no Apache será utilizada para os protocolos https e tls/ssl. Feito esta alteração, salve o arquivo e inicialize o Apache.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2. Se o problema for com a porta 80, altere para porta 81, editando o arquivo httpd.conf que está na pasta \apache\conf alterando a linha Listen 80 para Listen 81.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter colaborado e que este pequeno tutorial seja útil.

Abraço a todos.